# Cannot import more libraries when using cgo

Tags: cgo

I'm attempting to re-write some Go code in C mainly as a learning experience, however I have ran into an issue to which I cannot find the answer to elsewhere.

I am attempting to run the following code:

```
package conv

/*
#include <stdio.h>
int** ConvertStringToArray(char* str){
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
*/

import (
    "C"
    "unsafe"
)

func ToArrayGo(str string) [][]int {
    return nil // TODO
}

func ToArrayC(str string) [][]int {
    C.ConvertStringToArray(C.CString(str))
    return nil // TODO
}
```

If I comment out the unsafe import it works just fine, however when I add it in I get the following error with the go install/test commands:

37: error: 'ConvertStringToArray' undeclared (first use in this function)

This is also the case whenever I try to import any other libraries. Any help would be appreciated or even a redirect to a relevant issue (I've already looked but may have missed one).

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import "C"
```

should be a line unto itself, and the first import. Then you can

```
import (
  "unsafe"
)
```

as the next line.